# How to set previous state inside anchor tag using angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need to set the just previous state inside the anchor tag while navigating the menu. Here is my code:

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref=".profile">College Profile</a></li>
        <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref=".stream">College stream</a></li>
        <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref=".dept">College Department</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown " ui-sref-active="active">
            <a ui-sref="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Resource Management <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a ui-sref="#">Add User Role</a></li>
                <li><a ui-sref="#">Add Course</a></li>
                <li><a ui-sref="#">Add Section</a></li>
                <li><a ui-sref="#">Add Session</a></li>
                <li><a ui-sref="#">Add Semester</a></li>
                <li><a ui-sref="#">Add Unit</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref=".usermanagement">User Management</a></li>
        <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref=".role">User Role</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In this code I need when user will click on "Resource Management" menu. This menu will active and other menus will not active (here I am using active class for highlight the menu) and will show the just previous state page.

As it has some sub menus these sub menus will display in dropdown list. In this case all is coming properly but it's throwing the below error and `cursor:pointer` property also not coming on this menu.

Error:

```
Error: Could not resolve '#' from state 'dashboard'
    at Object.t.transitionTo (angularuirouter.js:7)
    at Object.t.go (angularuirouter.js:7)
    at angularuirouter.js:7
    at angularjs.js:146
    at e (angularjs.js:43)
    at angularjs.js:45
```

Answer (score 0):

ui-router doesn't track the previous state once it transitions, but the event **$stateChangeSuccess** is broadcast on the $rootScope when the state changes.

You should be able to catch the prior state from that event ("**from**" is the state you're leaving):

```
app.run(['$rootScope',function($rootScope)
{  
  $rootScope.previousState;
    $rootScope.currentState;
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(ev, to, toParams, from, fromParams) {
            $rootScope.previousState = from.name;
            $rootScope.currentState = to.name;
            console.log('Previous state:'+$rootScope.previousState)
            console.log('Current state:'+$rootScope.currentState)
        });
}]);
```

Comment: where i will add this.

Comment: You can add it everywhere you want because the previous and current state properties are added to the **$rootScope**...

By the way, AngularJS and UI.Router are able to manage the browser history so you can try with a simple *history.back*.

Comment: you have declared your states in app.config just above that paste the above code